# return PartialView[viewname, model] equivalent?

Tags: razor, nancy

I've got a site build with RazorViewEngine where using "_ViewStart.cshtml" to set the layout to "Shared/_Layout.cshtml". Then, I've the following module:

```
public class LogModule : NancyModule
{
    public LogModule()
    {
        Get["/log"] = _ =>
            {
                var list = GetLog().ToPagedList(1, 5);

                return View["Index", list];
            };

        Get["/log/{page:int}"] = _ =>
            {
                int pageNumber = _.page ?? 1;
                var list = GetLog().ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5);

                return View["_List", list];
            };
    }
}
```

And the following views:

Index.cshtml

```
@using Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor
@using PagedList
@inherits NancyRazorViewBase<IPagedList<LogModel>>

<h1>View Log</h1>    
<div id='container'>
    @Html.Partial("_List", Model)
</div>
```

_List.cshtml

```
@using Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor
@using PagedList   
@inherits NancyRazorViewBase<IPagedList<LogModel>>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var log in Model)
        {                                        
            <tr class="@log.Class">
                <td>@log.Date</td>
                <td>@log.Message</td>
            </tr>    
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="pagination" data-current="@Model.PageNumber" data-count="@Model.PageCount">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pager first">|<</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pager prev"><</a></li>            
                        <li class="active"><span>@Model.PageNumber / @Model.PageCount</span></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pager next">></a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pager last">>|</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And finally, some javascript code to manage ajax requests to the '/log/{page:int}" action and replace the 'container' div with the result. Sadly, this result contains a full page, including _Layout.cshtml and breaking all the page.

In MVC this is solved using return PartialView(viewName, Model) but I couldn't find something similar in NancyFx. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Partial View and View are the same in MVC, just alias', you would return a View in Nancy, same same. Just set your layout to null in the view so it doesn't load the default master.

Comment: Tried to set it to null, but it didn't worked. But there is a similar approach that do work. I stated it as the solution to the question. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Glad you sorted it, I'm pretty sure there's a better solution but I can't remember off the top of my head, there may be a new bug since I upgraded Razor to use the official release, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the solution is quite simple. Just create an 'empty' layout file with this single line:

```
@RenderBody()
```

And then use it in your partial view:

```
@{ Layout = "Shared/_EmptyLayout"; }
```